# How to fix my removal function in skiplist implementation in C code?

Tags: c, skip-lists

I have problems about skiplist removal, but I don't really see how it fails(A lot of testcases did work well), can someone help me? Thanks!

I think most of the functions and main structure are correct, only the removal has some potential problems, my list is based on a descending order. I need to include the cases of empty list or remove not-existed number(just skip it).

It has really confused me for a long time, I think I need to think of some extreme cases on this one.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
#include<limits.h>
#define MaxLevel 65

int currLevel = 0;

typedef struct Node
{
    long long data;
    struct Node *next;
    struct Node *last;
    struct Node *up;
    struct Node *down;
} Node;

typedef struct 
{
    int level;
    struct Node *node;
} skipStep;

bool CoinFlip(long long k, int i) 
{
    return k >> (i - 1) & 1;
}

void skiplist_insert(Node *SL[], long long data) 
{
    int level = currLevel;
    Node *last = NULL;

    skipStep steps[MaxLevel];
    for (int i = 0 ; i < MaxLevel; i++) 
    {
        steps[i].level = 0;
        steps[i].node = SL[i];
    }

    Node* Head = SL[level];
    Node* tmp = Head->next;

    while(level > 0 && data > tmp->data) 
    {
        level--;
        Head = SL[level];
        tmp = Head->next;
    }

    while(level > 0) 
    {
        while(tmp != NULL) 
        {
            if (data > tmp->data) 
            {
                steps[level].level = level;
                if (last != NULL) 
                {
                    steps[level].node = last;
                }
                tmp = last->down;
                level--;
                break;
            }
            last = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        if(tmp == NULL) 
        {                        
            steps[level].level = level;
            if (last != NULL) 
            {
                steps[level].node = last;
            }   
            tmp = last->down;
            level--;
        }
    }

    while (tmp != NULL) 
    {
        if (data > tmp->data) 
        {
            break;
        }
        last = tmp;
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    Node *newData = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newData->data = data;
    newData->up = NULL;
    newData->down = NULL;
    newData->last = NULL;
    newData->next = NULL;

    int k = 0;
    if(last == NULL) 
    {
        Head = SL[0];
        Node *headNext = Head->next;
        if(headNext != NULL) 
        {
            newData->next = headNext;
            headNext->last = newData;
            newData->last = Head;
        } 
        Head->next = newData;
        newData->last = Head;
    } 
    else if(tmp == NULL) 
    {
        last->next = newData;
        newData->last = last;
    } 
    else 
    {
        newData->next = tmp;
        tmp->last = newData;
        newData->last = last;
        last->next = newData;
    }

    while(CoinFlip(data, k + 1)) 
    {
        k++;
        if(k >= MaxLevel)
        { 
            break;
        }
        Node *newIndex = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newIndex->data = data;
        newIndex->down = newData;
        newData->up = newIndex;

        Node *node = steps[k].node;
        Node *nextIndex = node->next;

        node->next = newIndex;
        newIndex->last = node;
        newIndex->next = nextIndex;                
        if(nextIndex != NULL) 
        {
            nextIndex->last = newIndex;
        }          
        newData = newIndex;
        if (k > currLevel)
        { 
            currLevel = k;
        }
    }
}

Node *initSkipList(Node *skipList[]) 
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MaxLevel; i++) 
    {
        Node *newHead = (Node *)malloc(sizeof(Node));
        newHead->data = LLONG_MAX;
        newHead->down = NULL;
        newHead->up = NULL;
        newHead->next = NULL;
        newHead->last = NULL;
        skipList[i] = newHead;
    }
    return skipList[MaxLevel - 1];
}



Node *skiplist_search(Node *SL[], long long data) 
{
    if(SL[0]->next == NULL)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    int level = currLevel;
    Node *Head = NULL;
    Node *tmp = NULL;
    Node *last = NULL;
    
    Head = SL[level];
    tmp = Head->next;
    long long endQuery = -1;
    while(level > 0 && data > tmp->data) 
    {
        level--;
        endQuery = tmp->data;
        Head = SL[level];
        tmp = Head->next;
    }

    while(level > 0 ) 
    {
        while(tmp != NULL) 
        {
            if(data > tmp->data) 
            {      
                level--;
                endQuery = tmp->data;
                tmp = last->down;
                break;
            }
            printf("%lld ", tmp->data);
            last = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        if(NULL == tmp) 
        {
            tmp = last->down;
            endQuery = -1;
            level--;
        }
    }
    while(!level && tmp != NULL && tmp->data >= data)
    {
        printf("%lld ", tmp->data);
        tmp = tmp->next;
        if(tmp != NULL && tmp->data == data)
        {
            return tmp;
        }
        else if(tmp == NULL || tmp->data < data)
        {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}

Node *SlowGet(Node *SL[], long long data) 
{
    if(SL[0]->next == NULL || data > SL[0]->next->data)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    
    Node *Head = SL[0];
    Node *tmp = Head->next;

    while(tmp != NULL && data < tmp->data) 
    {
        printf("%lld ", tmp->data);
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    if(tmp != NULL && data == tmp->data) 
    {
        return tmp;
    } 
    else 
    {
        return NULL;  
    }
}

void skiplist_delete(Node *SL[], long long data) 
{
    int level = currLevel;
    Node *Head = NULL;
    Node *tmp = NULL;
    Node *last = NULL;

    Head = SL[level];
    tmp = Head->next;
    long long endQuery = -1;

    while(level > 0 && data > tmp->data) 
    {
        level--;
        endQuery = tmp->data;
        Head = SL[level];
        tmp = Head->next;
    }

    while(level > 0) 
    {
        while(tmp != NULL) 
        {
            if(data > tmp->data)
            {
                level--;
                endQuery = tmp->data;
                tmp = last->down;
                break;
            }
            last = tmp;
            tmp = tmp->next;
        }
        if(tmp == NULL) 
        {
            tmp = last->down;
            endQuery = -1;
            level--;
        }
    }
    
    while(tmp != NULL) 
    {
        if(endQuery != -1)
        {
            if(tmp->data > endQuery) 
            {
                tmp = NULL;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (tmp->data == data) 
        {
            break;
        }
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }

    if(tmp == NULL) 
    {
        return;
    }
    level = 0;
    Node *t_last = NULL;
    Node *t_next = NULL;
    while(tmp->up != NULL) 
    {
        level++;
        tmp = tmp->up;
    }
    while(tmp != NULL) 
    {
        t_last = tmp->last;
        t_next = tmp->next;

        Node *t_down = tmp->down;

        if (t_last == NULL) 
        {
            return;
        }

        t_last->next = t_next;

        if(t_next != NULL)
            t_next->last = t_last;
        else
            t_last->next = NULL;

        if(t_last == SL[level] && t_next == NULL) 
        {
            currLevel--;
        }
        free(tmp);

        tmp = t_down;
        level--;
        if(currLevel < 0)
        {
            currLevel = 0;
        }
        if(level < 0)
        {
            level = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main() 
{
    int M;
    scanf("%d", &M);
    Node *SL[MaxLevel];
    Node *skipList = initSkipList(SL);

    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i) 
    {
        int t;
        long long k;
        scanf("%d%lld", &t, &k);
        Node* node = NULL;
        switch(t) 
        {
            case 1:
                node = SlowGet(SL, k);
                if(node != NULL)
                {
                    printf("%lld", node->data);
                }
                else if(SL[0]->next == NULL || (node == NULL && k > SL[0]->next->data))
                {
                    printf("-1");
                }
                printf("\n");
                break;
            case 2:
                node = skiplist_search(SL, k);
                if (node != NULL)
                {
                    printf("%lld", node->data);
                }
                else if(SL[0]->next == NULL || (node == NULL && k > SL[0]->next->data))
                {
                    printf("-1");
                }
                printf("\n");
                break;
            case 3:
                skiplist_insert(SL, k);
                break;
            case 4:
                skiplist_delete(SL, k);
                break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have wrong answers when removal, and only one runtime error, since mostly correct, I really don't know what to inspect.

Comment: What is the main issue that you faced? Did you ```debug``` your code by setting a breakpoint and stepping into the code?

Comment: You never describe the problem.

Comment: How do you know that `tmp` points to a valid node in `while(level > 0 && data > tmp->data)`?